# What is Build Log file?

Tags: build, compilation

i'm looking for an explanation on Build Log file, what is it exactly and what is the structure of it?
I couldn't find clear explanation on the internet.

Comment: Is it not just a log file of the output of the build/compilation process?

Comment: @RandomDavis I don't know, that's why I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Build Log refers to the log when you try to build your program with the help of some build tools like, maven ant gradle etc. Each tool has its own approach of printing the logs onto the console. The build tool compiles your entire project like checking dependencies, downloading dependencies, compiling with the dependencies, generating jar, war ear files etc... and logs generated for all these activities together are referred to as build log. When you build your project, you look for the successful build message in the log or if any error occurs you refer to the error in the build log.